# How to import all the external libraries by jus import one file in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This might be answered somewhere, but i can't seem to find the answer.

i have various imports

```
import KeychainAccess
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import ...
import ...
import ...
```

Can i actually add all of them into one swift file and just `import HeaderHelper` ? I tried to import just as ObjC but gotten `No such module 'HeaderHelper'`

any point will be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a Swift bridging header would do the trick. As it is globally used. You'd have it imported everywhere though, kind of like a PCH for objective-c. Not a bad option IMHO.

Of course you'd have to import Objective-C style.

```
#import <YourFramework/YourFramework.h>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
most of my imports are swift based, will the bridging header work?

Comment: All frameworks should be visible to objective-c I believe. At least try it and see. Apple's ones will I know that much.

Comment: Remember that there are objective-c versions of headers created in reverse too

Comment: theres no header for swift libraries.

Comment: It should be generated by bridging. Otherwise it's looking bleak